# How to calculate a value in Javascript in an Acrobat form? - how do I write the result?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm totally new to Javascript as used in Acrobat forms.

I simply want to count the number of non-empty fields and write the result into another field. I've tried putting the following under calculate > custom calculation script:

```
var sum = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    f = "item" + i;
    if (getField( f ).valueAsString) {sum += 1;
    }
}
```

Is this correct and how do I actually write sum ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the "wonderful" world of Acrobat JavaScript (but then, web browser JavaScript or server-side JavaScript is about as "wonderful"…)

Anyway, PDF has its Document Object Model which needs to be understood (at least a little bit) when making forms smarter. Therefore, it is highly recommended to get the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the [Developer section of the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html).

Now, for your problem; if I understand correctly, you want to display how many of your fields have a value. The simplest way to do so, using your "itemx" names (where x is a number from 1 to 9), is something like this:

In the field where you display the number of fields having a value you add the following Custom Calculation script:

```
var cntr = 0 ;
for (var i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
if (this.getField("item" + i).value != this.getField("item" + i).defaultValue) {
cntr++ ;
}
}
event.value = cntr ;
```

And that would do it.

Comment: That's brilliant, many thanks Leonardo da Vinci. So the formula 'event.value = cntr' actually turns out to be an instruction to output? Weird!

Comment: Thanks for the flowers… Well, it is not really output; what that line of code does is set the value of the field where the script is run, while the script is run… you have to get used to the field event processing sequence, but when you get it, it provides an enormous potential with little coding effort.